# How to pass php variable from one div to another div in the same page than pass to another page?

Tags: php, jquery, html

I want to delete selected data from the database.Before deleting I will ask to user confirmation, if he agree only data will be deleted the database based on member_id.For this, I want value to included page (deleteUser.php).
How to do this one?.I know passing variable from one page to another using form and via href.But,here I am not getting how to pass the variable.

Can anyone assist me?

And I will get member_id via while loop like $userdetails['member_id']; in the code,

By using like this I can do.But I want to do using above code only.

```
<a href="http://localhost/Performance/login/deleteUser.php?" class="delete" name="delete" data-toggle="modal"><i class="material-icons" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Delete" Onclick="return ConfirmDelete()">&#xE872;</i></a>
```

My code is,

```
<?php
include_once "deleteUser.php";
?>
<table class="table table-striped table-hover">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>
                            <span class="custom-checkbox">
                                <input type="checkbox" id="selectAll">
                                <label for="selectAll"></label>
                            </span>
                        </th>
                        <th>Username</th>
                        <th>Email</th>
                        <th>Role</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <?php 
                while($userdetails = mysqli_fetch_array($res, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
                   echo' <tr>
                        <td>
                            <span class="custom-checkbox">
                                <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1" name="options[]" value="1">
                                <label for="checkbox1"></label>
                            </span>
                        </td>
                        <td>'.$userdetails['username'].'</td>
                        <td>'.$userdetails['email'].'</td>
                        <td>'.$userdetails['role'].'</td>
                        <td>
                            <a href="#editEmployeeModal" class="edit" data-toggle="modal"><i class="material-icons" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Edit">&#xE254;</i></a>
                            <a href="#deleteEmployeeModal" class="delete" name="delete" data-toggle="modal"><i class="material-icons" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Delete">&#xE872;</i></a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>';
                }?>
                </tbody>
            </table>
<div id="deleteEmployeeModal" class="modal fade">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <form  method="post"  action="#" method="post" autocomplete="off">
                    <div class="modal-header">                      
                        <h4 class="modal-title">Delete Employee</h4>
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">                    
                        <p>Are you sure you want to delete these Records?</p>
                        <p class="text-warning"><small>This action cannot be undone.</small></p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <input type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" value="Cancel">
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" name="deleteUser" value="Delete">
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

my deleteUser.php code,

```
include_once '../Connection/dbconnect.php';
if(isset($_POST['deleteUser'])){
    //further codes will be here
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: instead of sending data to another div, you can append a result in another div, and on click one of the options, then you can redirect the page or delete the data from the database

Comment: you do the above using AJAX/jQuery

Comment: Can you send me model code? I am beginner in Jquery. I  don't know how to do this.

Comment: I would have but I have to test the code first, but I dont have the correct platform to test it, I can send you the link. [Here](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_php.asp), check this. Take a reference from this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
if(isset($_POST['deleteUser'])){
     $member_id = $_POST['options'];

     // write delete sql query here
}
```